# PHP last added in array replaces all stored array values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

What I'm trying to do:

1. Get results from the database.
2. Get required values by assigning to an stdClass.
3. Put those objects in array. (<-The problem)
4. And output as JSON.

The objects are fine they get correct values. But when they are assigned to the array once, they replace all previous array values.

I'm using CodeIgniter to do the DB stuff.

The function:

```
function get_prizes(){

    //All prize objects are stored here
    $prizes = array();

    //Prize object
    $prize = new stdClass();
    $prize->name1 = '';
    //$prize->type = '';

    //Getting the prizes from a simple database table
    $query = $this->db->get('prizes');

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){

        foreach ($query->result() as $row):

            $prize_name = $row->prize_name;
            $prize->name1 = $prize_name;
            //$prize->type = $prize_name;

            $prizes[] = $prize;

            echo " Item:  " . print_r($prizes, true) . "<br>";

        endforeach;

    }

    echo json_encode($prizes);

}
```

Output:

```
Item: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name1] => Radio ) ) 
Item: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name1] => Television ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name1] => Television ) ) 
Item: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name1] => Toaster ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [name1] => Toaster ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [name1] => Toaster ) ) 
[{"name1":"Toaster"},{"name1":"Toaster"},{"name1":"Toaster"}]
```

I've tried array_push(). Also does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the object inside `foreach` loop:

```
function get_prizes()
{
    // All prize objects are stored here
    $prizes = array();

    // Getting the prizes from a simple database table
    $query = $this->db->get('prizes');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row):

            // Prize object    
            $prize = new stdClass();

            // $prize->type = '';
            $prize->name1 = $row->prize_name;

            $prizes[] = $prize;

        endforeach;
    }

    echo json_encode($prizes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. Why does it need to be instantiated inside? And how does it change values inside an array if they are already assigned?

Comment: In PHP objects are passed by reference, so when you create the object outside the loop, only one object will be used at each iteration and will be added to the array (with different index). The property `name1` will retain the last value which is `Toaster`; Thus, you need to create a new object at each iteration.